# Best Practice For Adding Reference to WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a class with a bunch of static const members in an external project (I use it basically like an enum) and one of my WCF services wants to use that class.

Is it better just to recreate the class within the service project or should I add an assembly reference in my WCF service project to the external project? It is kind of weird because the external project in this case is a ASP .NET MVC application. If I recreate the class, my service will be basically self-sufficient, but I would be repeating myself.

What is the best thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your static const members in their own assembly, and have the WCF Service and ASP.NET MVC application share it.